# aws-amplify AWSIoTProvider is not a constructor with Angular 8

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have followed below official link document [official link](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js#aws-iot). It is working fine with **ng serve** But when I **build** and than visit that page it is showing error like **"AWSIoTProvider is not a constructor "**.  I am not getting any solution for this.

```
import { AWSIoTProvider } from '@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib/Providers';
Amplify.addPluggable(new AWSIoTProvider({
     aws_pubsub_region: '<YOUR-IOT-REGION>',
     aws_pubsub_endpoint: 'wss://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.<YOUR-IOT-REGION>.amazonaws.com/mqtt',
   }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with "aws-amplify": "^3.0.8", I have down graded to "aws-amplify": "^2.2.6", this worked for me.